# RecyclerView - Scroll To Position Not Working Every Time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I have implemented a horizontal scrollable `RecyclerView`. My `RecyclerView` uses a `LinearLayoutManager`, and the problem I am facing is that when I try to use `scrollToPosition(position)` or `smoothScrollToPosition(position)` or from `LinearLayoutManager`'s `scrollToPositionWithOffset(position)`. Neither works for me. Either a scroll call doesn't scroll to the desired location or it doesn't invoke the `OnScrollListener`.

So far I have tried so many different combinations of code that I cannot post them all here. Following is the one that works for me (But only partially):

```
public void smoothUserScrollTo(final int position) {

    if (position < 0 || position > getAdapter().getItemCount()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "An attempt to scroll out of adapter size has been stopped.");
        return;
    }

    if (getLayoutManager() == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot scroll to position a LayoutManager is not set. " +
                "Call setLayoutManager with a non-null layout.");
        return;
    }

    if (getChildAdapterPosition(getCenterView()) == position) {
        return;
    }

    stopScroll();

    scrollToPosition(position);

    if (lastScrollPosition == position) {

        addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

                if (left == oldLeft && right == oldRight && top == oldTop && bottom == oldBottom) {
                    removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

                    updateViews();

                    // removing the following line causes a position - 3 effect.
                    scrollToView(getChildAt(0));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    lastScrollPosition = position;
}

@Override
public void scrollToPosition(int position) {
    if (position < 0 || position > getAdapter().getItemCount()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "An attempt to scroll out of adapter size has been stopped.");
        return;
    }

    if (getLayoutManager() == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot scroll to position a LayoutManager is not set. " +
                "Call setLayoutManager with a non-null layout.");
        return;
    }

//      stopScroll();

        ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0);
//        getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position);
    }
```

I opted for `scrollToPositionWithOffset()` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845742/smoothscrolltoposition-doesnt-work-properly-with-recyclerview) but the case perhaps is different as I use a LinearLayoutManager instead of GridLayoutManager. But the solution does work for me too, but as I said earlier only partially.

- When the call to scroll is from 0th position to totalSize - 7 scroll works like a charm.
- When scroll is from totalSize - 7 to totalSize - 3, First time I only scroll to 7th last item in the list. The second time however I can scroll fine
- When scrolling from totalSize - 3 to totalSize, I start getting unexpected behavior.

If anyone has found a work around I'd Appreciate it. Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/abbasshah17/6239ae4b71112e82c5f3) to my code of custom `ReyclerView`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I had the same issue some weeks ago, and found only a really bad solution to solve it. Had to use a `postDelayed` with 200-300ms.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourList.scrollToPosition(position);
    }
}, 200);
```

If you found a better solution, please let me know! Good luck!

Comment: Best solution I've found so far, is provided in the question it-self (Not good enough though!). Also not to be rude but your solution is quite crude! I'd rather Override LinearLayout's `scrollToPosition()` method then adopt this approach.

Comment: While I also think this solution is crude, this is the only solution that works so far :\ . thanks anyway!

Comment: This is the only solution which worked. 
First i called chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); then
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (list_chat.size() > 0) {
                                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(list_chat.size() - 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }, 200);

Comment: Calling recylerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position) instead of scrollToPosition(position) seems to solve this issue.

Comment: The 200 ms are needed as lower than this value won't do anything. Thanks for the answer

Comment: It seems like something runs in parallel with OnCreate() that resets the scroll position. When you set the scroll position in OnCreate() or OnResume() or OnStart() without a delay it just gets overwritten by this mysterious parallel process. I tried this in debug mode and stepped through the code before and after the scrolltoposition() method and it works just fine, presumably because by running the code line by line I introduce a delay to let this mysterious parallel process complete first before running the scrolltoposition() method. I think that's why the answer given here works.

Comment: The solution I found, was to run on the UI thread a call to setAdapter (with the same adapter I used already), followed by notifyDataSetChange, and then, from the background thread I'm using to call to myRecycleView.post(... with the scrollToPosition in it.... feels like a voodoo, but worked for me..

Comment: What if the device on which i am running this particular code is slow and even in those 200-300 ms the layout is not inflated then this trick would get failed.

Comment: Rather adding  yourList.scrollToPosition(position); in your activity add it in your adapter in onBindViewHolder method.

Comment: Its better to go with `myRecycleView.post(() -> myRecycleView.smoothScrollToPosition(position))`

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer will work, but it may also break. The main reason for this issue is that the recycler view may not be ready by the time you ask it to scroll. The best solution for the same is to wait for the recycler view to be ready and then scroll. Luckily android has provided one such option. Below solution is for Kotlin, you can try the java alternative for the same, it will work.

```
newsRecyclerView.post {
    layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(viewModel.selectedItemPosition)
}
```

The post runnable method is available for every View elements and will execute once the view is ready, hence ensuring the code is executed exactly when required.

Answer (score 18):

Turns out I was having a similar issue until I utilized

```
myRecyclerview.scrollToPosition(objectlist.size()-1)
```

It would always stay at the top when only putting in the objectlist size. This was until i decided to set the size equal to a variable. Again, that didn't work. Then I assumed that perhaps it was handling an outofboundsexception without telling me. So I subtracted it by 1. Then it worked.

Comment: I was wondering why smoothScrollToPosition() was working, but scrollToPosition() did not, and this was the answer! smooth scroll must not have cared that I was trying to scroll beyond the length of the list so it worked regardless. Thank you so much I would have never noticed this was the issue!

Answer (score 10):

So the problem for me was that I had a **RecyclerView** in a **NestedScrollView**. Took me some time to figure out this was the problem. The solution for this is (**Kotlin**):

```
val childY = recycler_view.y + recycler_view.getChildAt(position).y
nested_scrollview.smoothScrollTo(0, childY.toInt())
```

**Java** (credits to Himagi https://stackoverflow.com/a/50367883/2917564)

```
float y = recyclerView.getY() + recyclerView.getChildAt(selectedPosition).getY();    
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) y);
```

The trick is to scroll the nested scrollview to the Y instead of the RecyclerView. This works decently at Android 5.0 Samsung J5 and Huawei P30 pro with Android 9.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `LinearSmoothScroller` this worked every time in my case:

1. First create an instance of LinearSmoothScroller:

> ```
>   LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller=new LinearSmoothScroller(activity){
>             @Override
>             protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
>                 return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
>             }
>         };
> ```

2. And then when you want to scroll recycler view to any position do this:

> ```
> smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(pos);  // pos on which item you want to scroll recycler view
> recyclerView.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
> ```

Done.

Comment: Smoother scrollers are a bad idea for long lists. Lets take a list of 500 items or more. Do you really want to smooth scroll from pos 0 to 499?

Answer (score 9):

I also faced a similar problem (having to scroll to the top when the list is getting updated), but none of the above options worked 100%

However I finally found a working solution at https://dev.to/aldok/how-to-scroll-recyclerview-to-a-certain-position-5ck4 <sup>[archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210715204138/https://dev.to/aldok/how-to-scroll-recyclerview-to-a-certain-position-5ck4)</sup>

###### Summary

`scrollToPosition` only seems to work **when the underlying dataset is ready**.

So therefore `postDelay` works (randomly) but it's depending on the speed of the device/app. If the timeout is too short it fails. `smoothScrollToPosition` also only works if [the adapter is not busy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61403576/11649486).

To observe when the dataset is ready, a [`AdapterDataObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver) can be added and certain methods overridden.

The code that fixed my problem:

```kotlin
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver( object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onItemRangeInserted(
        positionStart: Int,
        itemCount: Int
    ) {
        // This will scroll to the top when new data was inserted
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution actually works, post or doOnNextLayout only works intermittent and if adding views to the bottom when already scrolled at the bottom i find not at all. Good find!

Answer (score 6):

None of the methods seems to be working for me. Only the below single line of code worked

```
((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(adapter.currentPosition(),200);
```

The second parameter refers to offset, which is actually the distance (in pixels) between the start edge of the item view and start edge of the RecyclerView. I have supplied it with a constant value to make the top items also visible.

Check for more reference over [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int))

Answer (score 4):

Using Kotlin Coroutines in Fragment or Activity, and also using  the lifecycleScope since any coroutine launched in this scope is canceled when the Lifecycle is destroyed.

```
  lifecycleScope.launch {
                delay(100)
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
Handler().postDelayed({
                    (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset( 0, 0)

}, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while creating a cyclic/circular adapter, where I could only scroll downward but not upward considering the position initialises to `0`. I first considered using Robert's approach, but it was too unreliable as the Handler only fired once, and if I was unlucky the position wouldn't get initialised in some cases.

To resolve this, I create an interval Observable that checks every XXX amount of time to see whether the initialisation succeeded and afterward disposes of it. This approach worked very reliably for my use case.

```
private fun initialisePositionToAllowBidirectionalScrolling(layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager, realItemCount: Int) {
        val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable() // Added here for clarity, make this into a private global variable and clear in onDetach()/onPause() in case auto-disposal wouldn't ever occur here
        val initPosition = realItemCount * 1000

        Observable.interval(INIT_DELAY_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe ({
                    if (layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                        layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(initPosition, 0)

                        if (layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == initPosition) {
                            Timber.d("Adapter initialised, setting position to $initPosition and disposing interval subscription!")
                            compositeDisposable.clear()
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    Timber.e("Failed to initialise position!\n$it")
                    compositeDisposable.clear()
                }).let { compositeDisposable.add(it) }
    }
```

Comment: Up-voting. Seems like better option then simply hoping 200 msec would do.

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly for when scrolling to last item in the recycler

```
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager())
                        .findLastVisibleItemPosition() != adapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
                }
            }
        }, 200 /* change it if you want*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty weird bug, anyway I managed to work around it without post or post delayed as follow:

```kotlin
list.scrollToPosition(position - 1)
list.smoothScrollBy(1, 0)
```

Hopefully, it helps someone too.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. My problem was, that I refilled the view with data in an async task, after I tried to scroll. From onPostExecute ofc fixed this problem. A Delay fixed this issue too, because when the scroll executed, the list had already been refilled.

Answer (score 0):

I use below solution to make the selected item in recycler view visible after the recycler view is reloaded (orientation change, etc). It overrides LinearLayoutManager and uses **onSaveInstanceState** to save current recycler position. Then in **onRestoreInstanceState** the saved position is restored. Finaly, in **onLayoutCompleted**, **scrollToPosition(mRecyclerPosition)** is used to make the previously selected recycler position visible again, but as Robert Banyai stated, for it to work reliably a certain delay must be inserted. I guess it is needed to provide enough time for adapter to load the data before scrollToPosition is called.

```
private class MyLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager{
    private boolean isRestored;

    public MyLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public MyLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state);
        if(isRestored && mRecyclerPosition >-1) {
            Handler handler=new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MyLayoutManager.this.scrollToPosition(mRecyclerPosition);
                }
            },200);

        }
        isRestored=false;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable savedInstanceState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("saved_state",savedInstanceState);
        bundle.putInt("position", mRecyclerPosition);
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        Parcelable savedState = ((Bundle)state).getParcelable("saved_state");
        mRecyclerPosition = ((Bundle)state).getInt("position",-1);
        isRestored=true;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use recyclerview in nestedScrollView you must scroll nestScrollview

```
nestedScrollview.smoothScrollTo(0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It's not so elegant way to do it, But this always works for me. Add a new method to the RecyclerView and use it insted of `scrollToPosition`:

```
public void myScrollTo(int pos){
    stopScroll();
    ((LinearLayoutManager)getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the Post Method, it will guarantee correct execution for any action

Answer (score 0):

This is the ultimate solution using kotlin in this date ... if you navigate to another fragment and go back and your recyclerview resets to the first position just add this line in onCreateView or wherever you need can call the adapter...

```
pagingAdapter.stateRestorationPolicy=RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
```

BTW pagingAdapter is my adapter with diffUtil.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, (but not the same), I try to explain it, maybe be could help someone else:

By the time I call to 'scrollToPosition' dataset is already set but some content like images loaded async (using Glide library) and probably when RecyclerView tries to compute the height amount to scroll down, image should return 0 as no loaded yet. So that gives an inaccurate scroll down I could solve it that way:

```
fun LinearLayoutManager.accurateScrollToPosition(position: Int) {
    this.scrollToPosition(position)
    this.postOnAnimation {
        val realPosition = this.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        if (position != realPosition) {
            this.accurateScrollToPosition(position)
        } else { 
            this.scrollToPosition(position) // this looks redunadant or inecessary but must be call to ensure accurate scroll
        }
    }
}
```

PD: In my case was not possible to know the size of the image to be loaded, if you know or you can resize the image you can add a placeholder on glide with de image size or override de size so recyclerView can compute the size correctly and don't need the above walkaraound.