# Smooth Scroll Not Working on Initial Scroll for Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scroll, linearlayoutmanager

I am working on an Android app that runs on only one devicerunning KitKat.

The smooth scrolling feature for a RecylerView I used that was working on other physical tablets and genymotion has unfortunately stopped working on the one device it needs to work on.

Instead of scrolling to a certain position it passes over the target position and scrolls all the way to the bottom and looks really bad.

I am able to track down the error to the abstract SmoothScroller in the RecyclerView class.

```
           if (getChildPosition(mTargetView) == mTargetPosition) {
                onTargetFound(mTargetView, recyclerView.mState, mRecyclingAction);
                mRecyclingAction.runIfNecessary(recyclerView);
                stop();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Passed over target position while smooth scrolling.");
                mTargetView = null;
            }
```

I was using a SnappingLinearLayoutManager that I found online, but swapped it out with the normal LinearLayoutManager from Android, and still am having the same problem.

The list is 7 items long (user can see 4 at a time) and I scroll to the 5th item (position 4) item.

When I scroll to the 3rd I don't receive this error.

Also after I scroll the list up and down once, the error stops happening.

EDIT: 
*I am able to use layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(); But I am trying to do this with the smooth scroll animation.*

Here is some of my code and details:

```
private void setupMainRecyclerViewWithAdapter() {
    mainLayoutManager = new SnappingLinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mainListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mainLayoutManager);

    settingsMainListAdapter = new SettingsListAdapter(SettingsActivity.this,
            settingsPresenter.getSettingsItems(),
            settingsPresenter);

    mainListRecyclerView.setAdapter(settingsMainListAdapter);

    mainListRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new BottomOffsetDecoration(EXTRA_VERTICAL_SCROLLING_SPACE));
}

@Override
public void scrollMainList(boolean listAtTop) {
    if(listAtTop) {
        mainListRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(4);
        moveMainMoreButtonAboveList();
    } else {
        mainListRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        moveMainMoreButtonBelowList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `layoutManager.scrollToPosition(index);` instead

Comment: Sorry I should say that I am able to use layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(); But I am trying to do this with the smooth scroll animation.

Good catch @BNK . I will add that edit to my question.

Comment: Perhaps they can help https://mcochin.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/android-customizing-smoothscroller-for-the-recyclerview/ and https://blog.stylingandroid.com/scrolling-recycler-view-part-2/

Comment: Yea I tried implementing the solution from the mcochin blog post, but ran into the same "Passed over target position while smooth scrolling." error. I will look into the other one.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

If you call `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos)` will be called immediately on the `UI thread` and if `recyclerView`'s `Adapter` is too much busy to generating view items then the calling of `smoothScrollToPosition` will be missed then because `recyclerView` has **no data** to smooth scroll. So it's better to do that in a background thread by `recyclerView.post()`. By calling this it goes into the `Main thread` queue and gets executed after the other pending tasks are finished.

Therefore you should do something like this which worked for my case:

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I realize it's too late, however I tried some different solutions and found one...

in custom LinearSmoothScroller I override updateActionForInterimTarget

```
@Override
 protected void updateActionForInterimTarget(Action action) {
      action.jumpTo(position);
 }
```

It's appears not very smooth, but not instant in contrast with scrollToPositionWithOffset.

Answer (score 2):

Just add one line for smooth scroll

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

it will work fine

Comment: worked for me, but can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: This is only applicable for recycler views with nested scroll areas

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [hasPendingAdapterUpdates()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#hasPendingAdapterUpdates()). You can use this along with a delay() for coroutines or Thread.sleep() to enable the backing data to be available before doing the scroll.