# Recyclerview smooth scrolling error

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I'm trying to smoothscroll to a position in recyclerview using linear layout manager.

`void smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`

However, it doesn't work correctly always. Sometimes, it takes me to the bottom of the list and in the logs, I get the following error message

`Passed over target position while smooth scrolling`

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845742/smoothscrolltoposition-doesnt-work-properly-with-recyclerview) in SO. However, the answer doesn't explain why the error is coming, it has solutions to cirumvent the problem. I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time. Could someone explain when this error will be thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `smoothScrollToPosition` in a background thread. Use`recyclerView.post()`. I guess the adapter may miss data when generating item view if it' s busy.