# How to wait for ListAdapter.submitList() to execute and call RecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I have a `RecyclerView recyclerView` which is linked to a `ListAdapter adapter`. The 'list' gets new data from Firebase database and the 'list' gets sorted based on certain object properties. I then call `adapter.submitList(list)` to update the recyclerView - this works perfectly!

But, I want the recyclerView to scroll to the top of the list after the new data is added. But I see that `adapter.submitList(list)` runs on a separate thread. So how would I go about knowing when it is done submitting and call `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);`

Let me know if I should provide more details.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845742/smoothscrolltoposition-doesnt-work-properly-with-recyclerview

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ListAdapter has got another overloaded version of submitList() `ListAdapter#submitList(@Nullable List<T> list, @Nullable final Runnable commitCallback)` that takes second argument as Runnable.

**As per the documentation:**

> The commit callback can be used to know when the List is committed,
>   but note that it
>        * may not be executed. If List B is submitted immediately after List A, and is
>        * committed directly, the callback associated with List A will not be run.

**Usage:**

```
    listAdapter.submitList(*your_new_list*, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do your stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: Take your internet point sir!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an AdapterDataObserver on your recyclerview adapter, that will happen after submit finish :

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            when {
                positionStart == 0 && itemCount != 0 -> {
                    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(itemCount)
                }
                positionStart > 0 -> {
                    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount)
                }
            }
        }

    })
```

Be careful with positionStart, item count value. There is also other callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chintan Soni said, you can make use of the submitList commit callback. Otherwise, and in case you're using kotlin coroutines and want to wait for animations to end, I would suggest getting a look at the `awaitSomething()` pattern.

```
recyclerView.awaitScrollEnd() // custom suspend extension function
```

more by Chris Banes on : https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/suspending-over-views-19de9ebd7020