# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException is occuring

Tags: java, android

I coded one handler to maintain the auto-scroll of a recyclerview. it's working fine. but the issue I am faced when there is only one item in the recyclerview. my app got crashed and when I checked logcat I am getting an error like java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid target position.

Here is my Custom LinearLayoutManager Class

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
        final LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller =
                new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {
                    private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 100f;

                    @Override
                    public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                        return CustomLinearLayoutManager.this
                                .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel
                            (DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                        return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                    }
                };
        linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
    }
}
```

Here is a getting error on this line:

```
startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
```

Error is - CustomLinearLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid target position

Here is the code for the home fragment

```
 recyclerViewHeaderSlider.setLayoutManager(new CustomLinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        headerSliderAdapter.setOnClick(this);
        recyclerViewHeaderSlider.setAdapter(headerSliderAdapter);
        final int speedScroll = 6000;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int count = 0;
            boolean flag = true;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (count < headerSliderAdapter.getItemCount()) {
                    if (count == headerSliderAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                        flag = false;
                    } else if (count == 0) {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    if (flag) count++;
                    else count--;

                    recyclerViewHeaderSlider.smoothScrollToPosition(count);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, speedScroll);
                }
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, speedScroll);
```

Here is a getting error on this line:

```
recyclerViewHeaderSlider.smoothScrollToPosition(count);
```

Error is - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid target position

Answer (score 9):

The error is due to a negative index (-1).

Look at this code:

```
if (count == headerSliderAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
    flag = false;
} else if (count == 0) {
    flag = true;
}
```

If your item count is 1, then the first `if` will be `true` when `count == 0`.
1 - 1 = 0 so `flag = false`.

Then, when you get to the second `if`:

```
if (flag) count++;
else count--;
```

`flag` is `false` so your code will execute `count--` but `count` is already 0, thus you get `count == -1`.

Then you try to scroll to a negative position, which is not allowed.

Comment: Please, can you give me a rectify code for this? It should work like when there is only 1 item in recyclerview it will not crash. and when there is more than 1 item in recyclerview it starts auto-scrolling.

Comment: @AparnaSharma Lev basically told you exactly what your error was. From this point it should be your responsibility to look at your code, and fix the mistake based on Lev's explanation. If you don't quite understand why this piece of code is problematic, I suggest you use a debugger to look at your code while it is executing so that you can see for yourself the state of your application. "_Give meh the codez_" type of requests are never welcomed on SO, you have to demonstrate that you have spent some effort to fix the problem by yourself.

Comment: @AparnaSharma sorry, but I can't fix your code, since I don't know why you wrote it the way you did. What is the `flag` variable for? Why not handle the count in the first if? Where do you want to scroll? Work out your logic first, then write code that matches it. If you still have a problem, show the new code.

Comment: @LevM. I edited my post. have a look at my whole code. You edit this code in a way you want I don't have any problem in this. I simply want when there is one item in my recyclerview it will not scroll or crash. but when there is more than 1 item in recyclerview it will auto-scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Lev M. it can be also (in case of last position):

```
private fun scrollToLastItem(view: View) {
    adapter.itemCount.takeIf { it > 0 }?.let {
        view.recycler_view.smoothScrollToPosition(it - 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use post delayed method that isn't thread-safe.

```
    private fun scrollToLastItem(view: View) {
      //pos.coerceAtLeast(0) // Use this 
       view.recycler_view.smoothScrollToPosition(pos.coerceAtLeast(0))
    }
```

RCA: The current position was -1 before the crash in the ScrollLayoutManager startSmoothPendingScroll method.